# (IIS7) How to configure the w3wp process to never go down

Tags: iis-7

I have one web app installed on one of my web servers. 
Its quick response is a must for user experience (i.e. returns phrases to the autocomplete)

After this application spops receiving requests for a while, w3wp process goes down and on the next request, the response time will be longer, as it will take also the time to load the w3wp process.

Is there a way to configure the w3wp process to never go down?
Is my only solution is to write an exe that sends dummy request every 1 minute?
Is there a built in "Keep alive" mechanism?

Thanks.

Comment: What William said ;)  It's in IIS, under Application Pools, under "advanced settings".  We have sites where the "Idle Time-out (minutes)" is set to 720, and the "Shutdown Time Limit (seconds)" is set to 7200.  NOTE ALSO that your web application may have its own timeouts, for example on caching... if it's an ASP.NET website, they may be in your web.config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Application Pool settings, change the value used for `Idle-Timeout` within the `Process` section. I believe the default is 20 minutes.